# Redirect specific URL to other URL based on user agent in .htacess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect one specific URL to another specific URL based on the user agent (everyone on mobile) through my .htaccess - I am overlooking something

I have googled like crazy but can't find a solution which works - I think there's a syntax mistake in the code snippet

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPad|iPhone|Android|Blackberry [NC]  
RewriteRule ^/specificurl1.html$ https://example.net/specificurl2.html [L,R,NC]
```

The expected outcome is for anyone who enters url1 from an android or iphone should be redirected to url2, while fx. desktop users will see url1. However url1 shows up no matter what device I try

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting this code snippet in an htaccess file, then the `RewriteRule` is wrong. The module doesn't receive the URL path including the forward slash you're matching against.

Try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPad|iPhone|Android|Blackberry [NC]  
RewriteRule ^specificurl1\.html$ https://example.net/specificurl2.html [L,R,NC]
```

The `\.` is simply to have a more exact match, since `.` in itself matches all possible characters.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help, unfortunately it doesn't do the trick. I've implemented your corrections but no matter if I change the user agent in my browser or try to access the URL from my actual phone I am not being redirected...

Comment: Can you provide a few URL samples which you want to redirect (and to where)?